# Get unique values from Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table data with have 100.000 rows+ and its content like below;

```
Service    Owner
ABC        JOHN
ABC        MARK
ABC        MARK
ABC        STEVE
ABC        STEVE
```

The output what i want is like below. Only getting unique values for services;

```
Service     Owner
ABC         JOHN
ABC         MARK
ABC         STEVE
```

How can i select the query?

Comment: Please explain your logic.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the distinct service and owner will give you the unique combinations of service and owner.

```
SELECT DISTINCT service,owner FROM TABLE
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4162/1).

Comment: Why? Help out by explaining -a bit- why does it solve OP's question

Comment: @Alfabravo - Done!

Comment: your answer and below answer gives me different rows count.

Comment: @john true - Added a SQLFiddle, which is producing the output you listed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

An aggregate query should do the trick:

```
SELECT   MIN(service), owner
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY owner
```

Comment: your answer and above answer gives me different rows count

Comment: the other answer have more rows.

Comment: This would work for the sample data and give the expected output. It sounds like you have rows where one owner has multiple services. If that is the case and you would like to see all unique services tied to the owner, you should go with the `select distinct` answer.